# Check whether update_batch() is successful in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm running update_batch() on a table in CodeIgniter and I'd like to check whether it was successful.

I've tried using affected_rows(), but that only counts the number of form fields that have been modified so it doesn't quite cut it:

```
$this->db->update_batch("sections", $data, "alias");

log_message("debug", "items in form: ".count($data));
// items in form: 3

log_message("debug", "rows updated: ".$this->db->affected_rows()); 
// rows updated: 0-3 
// depending on whether anything was actually changed on the form

return ($this->db->affected_rows() == count($data)); // unreliable
```

It seems like a fairly straightforward thing to ask from a batch update function. Is there something I've missed or should I just write my own batch update code?

Comment: Is using Transactions instead of CI's `update_batch` an option for you?

Comment: I'm working with MyISAM on this project since it's for a simple CMS which wouldn't get updated very often. Good call though, I might consider switching to InnoDB.

Answer (score 4):

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->update_batch($table, $update, $variable);
    $this->db->trans_complete();        
    return ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)? FALSE:TRUE;
```

Hope this helps!. Cheers!

Comment: If this works, can it be marked as the solution? Or perhaps there is an issue with this answer?

Comment: just wondering? Why are you using transactions with this example? The documentation example does not show the need for transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple instruction this will return true or false

```
return $this->db->update_batch("sections", $data, "alias");
```

Comment: This doesn't work on the current stable version that I originally tried it on (2.1.0 at the time of writing). However, looking at the Git repo it's already implemented in the dev branch of 3.0 here: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php