# Codeigniter Update Multiple Records with different values

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to update a certain field with different values for different records.

If I were to use MySql syntax, I think it should have been:

```
UPDATE products
SET price = CASE id
    WHEN '566423' THEN 49.99
    WHEN '5681552' THEN 69.99
END
WHERE code IN ('566423','5681552');
```

But I prefer to use Active Record if it's possible.

My input is a tab delimited text which I convert into an array of the id and the desired value for each record:

```
$data = array(
               array(
                  'id' => '566423' ,
                  'price' => 49.99
               ),
               array(
                  'id' => '5681552' ,
                  'price' => 69.99
               )
    );
```

I thought this is the proper structure for update_batch, but it fails. Here's what I've tried:

```
function updateMultiple()
{
    if($this->db->update_batch('products', $data, 'id'))
    {
        echo "updated";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed )-:";
    }

}
```

And I get failed all the time. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have logging enabled?  If so, are there any errors output by CodeIgniter for that query?

Comment: hmmm... I'm quite a newbie in this. Where should the logging be enabled?

Comment: Codeigniter active record doesnt support Case syntax so you will have to do with standard SQL. (Logging is enabled in config.php -set level 4)

Comment: @einav - in `application/config/config.php`, you can set your `log_threshold`.  Your logs should be visible in `application/logs`.

@jtheman - codeigniter does in fact support a function called `update_batch` which produces the CASE command einav is looking for

Comment: @Darrrrrren thanks I learned something

Comment: thanks, @Darrrrrren. I enabled logging, and I guess this is the problem:

ERROR - 2012-11-07 00:05:20 --> Severity: Warning  --> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() /Users/einav/Sites/testingCI/system/database/DB_active_rec.php 1399


What does it mean?

Comment: And not sure if I missed it before, or it showed up only now after I enabled logging, but the page now actually shows a Database error:<br>
One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index./// Which one is the index?

Comment: That would appear to be saying that one of your associative arrays is missing the "id" index.

Comment: @Darrrrrren, You're right. Foolishly, I was passing the wrong array to the update_batch. Grrrr!
Anyway, after fixing it, I am still getting "failed" - but the database is updated correctly. Turns out update_batch isn't returning true upon success. See the last comment in this thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398907/check-whether-update-batch-is-successful-in-codeigniter)

Comment: OK.  Glad you got everything (relatively) sorted out :-)