# Codeigniter Database Error persists

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

These are my settings in the database config file for Codeigniter:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'admin',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => FALSE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

And even if I set the debuging to false errors still show on my page specificly after this function:

```
if ($this->db->update_batch($batch_data, 'id'))
{
    echo 'Success';
}
else
{
    echo 'Error';
}
```

I know why this happens (incorrect id value and in this case missing argument) but I don't know why the error is displayed and more importantly why is there no `false` on return? Instead it returns the "A Database Error Occurred" block!

Comment: There is no return. The script is failing and CI is displaying an error page much like the built in 404 error page. This type of display is unrelated to the `db_debug` setting. If you turn error reporting off I don't think the page will show up. But of course your operation will still be a failure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398907/check-whether-update-batch-is-successful-in-codeigniter

Comment: @DFriend How come I can get inside of `if()` statement if my batch update is successful but not inside `else` if like you say, there is no return?

Comment: You don't get to the `else` because script execution ended during `update_batch()`. In other words, `update_batch()` does not return so the `if()` statement does not get evaluated. This happens because `update_batch()` uses `set_update_batch()`. In that function, if the 'where' key is missing or does not match up with value keys then `display_error()` is called. `display_error()` loads and displays the error page and finishes with a call to `exit(8);` As you know `exit()` terminates the current script.

Comment: The moral of the story: Always confirm all function params are valid before calling `update_batch()`.

Comment: @DFriend thank you fpr explaining, is there a way to turn off such reports though, because setting database config and environment to production doesn't do anything...

Comment: There is not a way that I know about. The alternative is failing silently which will likely leave the end-user sitting there angry that nothing is happening. You definitely don't want an update to run if the where statement is suspect. That's a recipe for over-writing every record in your database with the same set.of values.